# Does passenger not work with Rewrite rules in an .htaccess file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-rewrite, passenger, mod-rails

I have a rewrite rule that only works when in a virtualhost context.

```
PassengerEnabled on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/release-.+/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|system|assets)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

If I set `PassengerEnabled off` in the .htaccess file, the rewrite rules work fine, otherwise they only work in the `<VirtualHost>` site config.

Is there a way to have rewrite rules be used in the .htaccess file with passenger?

Answer (score 0):

Passenger should be compatible with mod_rewrite by default as long as [PassengerHighPerformance](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerHighPerformance) is off.

If you're using an older version of Phusion Passenger you might want to make sure [RailsAllowModRewrite](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_railsallowmodrewrite) is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks. PassengerHighPerformance is set to off and I'm using the latest version ( 3.0.6 )